# How to save your typed python program in Windows PowerShell?

Tags: python, windows, save

I'm currently learning Python. I downloaded Python 3.9 and typed a few lines of code in Windows PowerShell which was present in my Laptop. After writing some lines of python program in PowerShell and pressing the Enter button, it immediately shows the output immediate below to the entered code. But, how do I save my this typed python program in PowerShell ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a text editor instead, Powershell isn't a text editor, you use Powershell to give instructions such as Launch python. IDLE comes with python and is fairly easy, I personally like VS Code for python as it's easily to set to launch Python programs.
Pycharm is my current IDE for Python but it's absolutely overkill for starters.

VS Code mate, and remember save your programs as .py

Comment: okay. Thank you !